# Export to Excel is not working for Multiple tab. Always exporting first tab data in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

**Export to excel is not working for multiple tab. I am using blob to export the table**

**Js File**

```
 $scope.ChartData = function(){ 
        var fromdate = $scope.formattedDate($scope.statisticsFromDate);
        var todate = $scope.formattedDate($scope.statisticsToDate);
         var data = $scope.charts;
         var xlHeaders =['Type','Title','Id','TechId','Data','From','To'];
         var xlFields=['type','title','id','techId','data',fromdate,todate];
         var xlfileName= 'Chartdetails.xls'; 
         $scope.exportData(data,xlHeaders, xlFields, xlfileName);
         console.log('statisticsFromDate',$scope.statisticsFromDate);
         console.log('statisticsToDate',$scope.statisticsToDate); 
         };

    // function to export chart data to excel
    $scope.exportData = function(data,xlHeaders, xlFields,xlfileName){

        console.log(document.getElementById('exportable1'));
        $scope.xcdata = data;
        $scope.xlHeaders = xlHeaders;
        $scope.xlFields = xlFields;
        $scope.xlfileName = xlfileName;
        $timeout(function layout() {
         var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable1').innerHTML], {
                type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
            });
            saveAs(blob, $scope.xlfileName);

    }, 2000);
    };
```

**HTML Code**

```
             <div id="exportable1" ng-show="true">
                    <table border="1">
                         <thead>          
                           <tr>
                                <th ng-repeat="header in xlHeaders" style="background-color:#124191;color:white">{{header}}</th>
                           </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="data in xcdata">
                                <td>{{data.type}}</td>
                                <td>{{data.title}}</td> 
                                <td>{{data.id}}</td> 
                                <td>{{data.techId}}</td>
                                <td >
                                <table ng-repeat="d in data.data">
                                    <tr ng-repeat="e in d">
                                        <td>{{e.x}}</td>
                                        <td> : {{e.y[0]}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                </td>
                                 <td>{{statisticsFromDate |date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                                <td>{{statisticsToDate  |date : 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
                            </tr> 
                        </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

**Tab :**

[image]

**TAB file Html**

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> <!-- ng-init="tabid = tab.active"> -->
      <li ng-class="{'active-tab':tablist[0].active}" ng-show="permissions.home" ng-click="showtab('LP')"><a class="search-tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></a></li>  
      <li ng-class="{'active-tab':tablist[1].active}" ng-click="showtab('SR')"><a class="search-tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'active-tab':tablist[2].active}" ng-show="tablist[2].showtab" ng-click="focusAdmin()"><a><button class="close closeTab" type="button" ng-click="closeAdmin()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"/></button>Administration</a></li>
      <li ng-class="{'active-tab':tab.active}" ng-repeat="tab in tablist | filter:{tabid:'!LP'} | filter:{tabid:'!SR'} | filter:{tabid:'!ADMIN'}" ng-click="showtab(tab.tabid)"><a><button class="close closeTab" type="button" ng-click="removeCustomerTab(tab.tabid)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"/></button>{{tab.title}}</a></li></ul>
```

We have TAB1 and TAB2.
Test Cases :
1. if I open Tab1 and export the data it will export it properly and close the Tab1 and open Tab2 then it will also export properly.( test case pass)
2. If I open the tab1 and export the data (don't close tab1) and open tab2 and exoprt the data it's exporting the tab1 data only why?
3. if I open Tab1 and now open tab2 and export for tab2 then it's exporting blank.

Please help to find out the solution.

Comment: post a fiddle with issue

Comment: and where is tab???

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal, I have added code for the Tabs. 4th <li> is creating multiple tabs.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue's fixed.**

Actually, the issue was happening due to static div ID. So for the multiple tabs, there were only one static ID.

**Previous:**

```
  <div id="exportable1" ng-show="true"
```

**Now:**

```
 <div id="{{activeTab}}" ng-show="false">
```

That's the reason, for every tab it was fetching first ID table data only.
Now Setting Every tab id in the session and same Tab id setting in div. Now table id is bind with tab ID.

**Main.js:**

```
  sessionStorage.setItem("activeTab", tabid);
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.activeTab = sessionStorage.getItem("activeTab");
```

I hope it's clear. Thanks